# Is there an API call to list all available product id's (ID's alone) in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I use *POSTMAN GUI* for retrieving a list of items from Shopify API.

I would like to know if there exists a way to get available product id's alone, preferably as a list of values over a single api `GET` call. The one I know of is

```
/admin/api/2022-04/products.json
```

It returns a list of all product information, and looping over them/traversing the json is not very efficient. I hope there must be an easy way to fetch all ID's alone in one go. Should there be not?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `/admin/api/2022-04/products.json?fields=id` to the end of your request to limit the output only for a single field or multiply.

Please note that if you have more than 250 products you will need to make more than one request, since the request is limited to 250 products.

Comment: Thanks, but, uhm, how should the second request be? From my understanding, the request you provided returns the same output, as chronologically ordered by shopify. Should i add a second paginator like request parameter, to fetch the list of next *50* products so to speak?

Comment: If you like to increase the limit to the max you need to add a `limit` get argument as well. Check the response directly in your shopify admin `https://YOUR_STORE_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/products.json?fields=id&limit=250`  just change the store name to yours to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one call to the Admin API for all your product IDs using the Bulk Query. That will result in you receiving a URL where you download a file in JSONL format with every single product ID in your store, without the paging or limits of other approaches.